# Word choice - Opening of a gap

Tags: word-choice

Looking for a word to describe the opening or widening of a gap. Like, if you are experiencing an earthquake and the earth opened in front of you, how you you describe that with "Oh look, the ground is __________-ing !!"?

Gaping's original word is "gape", so that's definitely incorrect.

Is there word that I can use to describe something like that concisely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "gap" that opens in the ground is called a "fissure":

> [**fissure**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fissure) (n): A long, narrow opening or line of breakage made by cracking or splitting, especially in rock or earth.

"Fissure" is also a verb:

> **fissure** (v): Split or crack (something) to form a long, narrow opening.

However, while something can be "fissuring", this is not common -- my online spell checker actually marks it as wrong, despite it being a valid word.  Instead it's more common to use one of *split*, *split open*, or just *open*:

> Look, a **fissure** is **opening** in the ground!

Other words like fissure:  *crack, cleft, crevice, cleavage, gap.*

There are other words used with other materials.  Fabric can be *rent*, *ripped*, *torn*, or various others.  A pizza can be *split*, *cut*, *sliced* into wedges.  Various things can be *severed*.

And so on.  If you provide a specific context, I can tell you the most appropriate options.

Comment: I like fissuring! It works, people understand it, and who cares about spell checker :p

Comment: Okay, I know, I should worry about proper-ness. But I am doing technical writing, where people invent words like, every second anyway. So- why not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, ***opening*** is a pretty good one. The ground doesn't usually do that, so it's certainly something worthy of pointing out.

You could also use ***splitting***. That's a nice everyday word, but it doesn't have quite the urgency of *opening*, to my mind.

If you were talking about it later, you could say that the ground ***was cleft*** (or *cleaved*, depending on dialect), if you want to be poetic. No-one would say that as it was happening, though.

If there's two separate objects, or two parts of one object separating, you could use ***to part***. Or indeed ***to separate***.

There isn't a verb specifically for "a gap appearing in something". Well, there might be some esoteric word in a dictionary somewhere, but there's no *everyday* word for that.

Comment: The earthquake one is only an example actually. I was describing something that has two parts, and a gap started appearing between them. I mean, opening up works, but it is not a very elegant way of saying it. I was just thinking whether there's some other better word for it.

Comment: @Isa: I added two more possibilities.